# What might slow Inkscape down when working with QGIS SVG or PDF output?

Tags: qgis, inkscape

When I import an SVG or PDF exported from QGIS print composer (2.2.0) into Inkscape 0.48 the vector graphic has large black lines and squares. These change size when I zoom in and out, and the graphic is very difficult to manage in Inkscape (slow reaction time when moving around the page and during difficult to group and ungroup vector layers). The map is not large (800 KB) and because it works perfectly other graphic programs (e.g., CorelDraw X5 and LibreOffice Draw 4.1) I believe it is a direct problem with Inkscape. Any suggestions?

Comment: Most likely it is the number of vertices in the original data - use some generalisation on the data.

Comment: Hi Mapperz. Thanks for the reply. I tried to the simplify geometries tool and then the check geometry validity tool. Still no luck. How do you do vector generalizations?

Comment: In QGIS 2.2 Vector> Geometry Tools> Simplify Geometries use a tolerance to see a difference.

Comment: @Mapperz It worked! I increased the Simplify tolerance from 0,0001 to 0,0020. This reduced the number of vertices from 98265 to 8808. While this created several topology gaps I was able to import the SVG and PDF into Inkscape and the graphic no longer contained black lines or squares. It is also now very easy to maneuver and group and ungroup the polygons. Thank you very much. While the simplify tool was effective, I am still confused as to why Inkscape fails to properly load the original map (bug perhaps?).

Comment: Also, thank you @underdark for editing the original title of my question.

Comment: As you've deduced, Inkscape handles shapes with a large number of vertices badly. Fortunately it looks like there's been improvements made to this in the upcoming release - see http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.91#Rendering_and_performance

Comment: @ndawson I really hope the new release works better with handling shapes. Unfortunately, until this is fixed I am going to have to use alternative programs.